# Using *_path(:param => @param) in link_to is not passing the param to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

Here is my setup:  Rails 3.2.13

I've already passed in a parameter "restaurant_id" for new, and am now trying to pass that same parameter via a submit button for create.  However, it doesn't seem to recognize the parameter for create.

For new:

```
<%= link_to t('.new', :default => t("helpers.links.new")),
            new_reservation_path(:restaurant_id => restaurant.id),
            :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

This properly passes in restaurant.id for new in the controller.  Then, on the new view, I have a submit button:

For create:

```
<%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
    reservations_path(:restaurant_id => @restaurant.id), :class => 'btn' %>
```

What I want to do here is pass in the restaurant.id again when creating and saving the object.  However, it does not show up in the create method.  @restaurant.id validly produces the correct id on it's own, but does not pass through.

Here is my controller:

```
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @reservation = Restaurant.find(params[:restaurant_id]).reservations.new
        @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:restaurant_id])
    end

    def create
        @reservation = Restaurant.find(params[:restaurant_id]).reservations.new(params[:reservation])

        if @reservation.save
          redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Reservation was successfully created.'
        else
          render action: "new", notice: 'There was an error.'
        end
    end
end
```

When it tries to find the restaurant, I get a No ID error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ReservationsController#create

Couldn't find Restaurant without an ID
```

When I test in the controller for :restaurant_id, it returns blank.

It's strange as I'm using the exact same method to pass :restaurant_id to my new controller, yet it doesn't work when I pass it to my create controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the code for that submit button, but since that submit button sends a form, you need to pass the parameter as a hidden field(either [hidden_field](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-hidden_field) or [hidden_field_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-hidden_field_tag). Arguments after the `?` in the path in an HTML form's `action` simply won't get passed.

Comment: <%= hidden_field_tag :restaurant_id, @restaurant.id %>

Thanks!  I was able to pass it through using this.